# Why console shows message when write message to file descriptor 0 1 2

Tags: c, linux

I write a message to file descriptor 0(stdin) 1(stdout) 2(stderr), I am not very sure why the message can be printed in console...

```
int main(void) {
  char buf[] = "Hello World";

  write(0, (void *)buf, strlen(buf));
  write(1, (void *)buf, strlen(buf));
  write(2, (void *)buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

Comment: Because that's what they're attached to, unless you've redirected them.

Comment: See the related question [Why is it possible to write() to STDIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822580/why-is-it-possible-to-write-to-stdin).

Comment: Where else do you think the output should go?